# Foundation 5: Horizontal Scroller: full screen div needed

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, horizontal-scrolling

I am very new to Foundation but found it to be very useful.
I am making a horizontal scroller website.
I have a fixed top bar.
There have to be different background images after each scroll.
Different images have to be in different div, Its a 10 page website, so I have set the body height as 1000px and width as 12000px, I am not able to set properties of the div.

```
<div class="row">
  <div id="home123" class="large-12 columns">
  </div>
</div>

#home123{
background-color: red;
}
```

this isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Make one page whole div and give css properties and another whole page a div and give different css properties

Comment: Thanks for answering. But thats what I am trying to do and the code is posted above, I am unable to make a whole page div using foundation. Please Guide.